# Sugges Best solution for this 1064 error

Tags: php

I get this message when i try to run the website:

> You Have An Error In Your SQL Syntax; Check The Manual That
>   Corresponds To Your MySQL Server Version For The Right Syntax To Use
>   Near 'Subscription) AND `Type` = 'Group' )' At Line 1 SQL=SELECT
>   Item_id FROM Hmvrd_acctexp_itemxgroup WHERE ( `Group_id` IN (Normal
>   Subscription) AND `Type` = 'Gro

Comment: Where does phpMyAdmin fit in to this? What website are you trying to run?

Comment: What Normal Subscription is here?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM hmvrd_acctexp_itemxgroup 
WHERE group_id IN (1,2,3) AND `Type` = 'Group'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select query should have to be like this, you must have to enter `group_id` integer because in  table you can see `group_id` is integer

```
SELECT Item_id FROM Hmvrd_acctexp_itemxgroup WHERE ( Group_id IN (1,2,3) AND Type = 'Group'
```